# How to test otp login in cypress?

Tags: next.js, cypress, e2e-testing, one-time-password, e2e

How does one E2E test OTP login?

I have set up an OTP login, I want to write a Cypress test for it where the user enters the OTP and gets it in email. How do I write a test for this, given that the OTP changes every time I send an email?

The current solutions I have are:

1. To create a test account and hardcode a static OTP for it on the server.
2. To create a mock API with static responses and use that for testing (currently I'm using the actual deployed API for testing)

Comment: I think the best way to check OTPs is to use an endpoint of the service that is generating the OTP. Fetch the OTP from the Request and then use it in the web app.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding your requirement, you can use [otplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/otplib) to bypass the email reading/parsing stage and directly generate the token that would otherwise be sent to the user in an email.

The package [cypress-otp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-otp) is a thin wrapper around `otplib`, but unfortunately it's not up-to-date and is awfully noisy and hard to follow for such a simple task.

This is how I unraveled the code and updated for **Cypress ver 10.10.0**:

**Install `otplib`**

- `yarn add -D otplib` or `npm install otplib --save-dev`

**Add a task to call otplib from you test**

This takes the place of reading a mail and parsing out the token, which you don't need to test because normally a user does that and enters the token into your app under test.

In **cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const otplib = require("otplib");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        generateToken(secret) {
          return otplib.authenticator.generate(secret);
        }
      })
    },
  },
});
```

**Example test taken from `cypress-otp` (simplified)**

```js
describe('Example of generating a token for use in OTP tests', () => {

  let secret;  // in this example, secret is taken from the app page, 
               // but normally you will pass it in from a fixture
               // or an environment variable

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://otplib.yeojz.dev');   // we use this page as a sample app

    // Get the secret
    cy.contains("Demo Secret")
      .parent().parent()
      .find('input').invoke('val')
      .should('not.eq', 'Loading...')       // simpler than waitUntil()
      .then(value => secret = value)
  })

  it('tests the token entry', () => {
    cy.task('generateToken', secret)
      .then(token => {
        cy.contains('Verify Token').click();

        cy.contains('Please input a token')
          .parent()
          .find('input')
          .type(token);

        cy.contains('The token is valid in this current window')
          .should('be.visible')
    })
  })
})
```

This test is the one given in `cypress-otp`, a simplified version of it which is more easily understood with moderate programming skills.

It's a bit contrived, because the app provides both the secret and the token, and then also verifies it.

The essential part is the `cy.task('generateToken', secret)` which makes receiving the token very easy.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is sending OTP via emails then I have a solution for you.

**Mailhog.**

You can point the SMTP to mailhog and all the outbound emails will appear in Mailhog's management console. Something like this.

[image]

After that it's a piece of cake. You can access those email inside cypress tests using this plugin.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-mailhog

It's been two months but I hope this helps.